# Get CSV file from URL and convert it to array - Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I'm trying to get earthquake data, and turn it into an array so I can use that data to visualise earthquakes on a map. I'm writing this script:

```
import requests
import csv


def csv_to_array(a):
    b = requests.get(a)
    my_file = open(b, "rb")
    for line in my_file:
        el = [i.strip() for i in line.split(',')]
        return el
```

which I import into another module, and:

```
import csvToArray
data = csvToArray.csv_to_array(
"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.csv")
i = 1
while i < len(data):
    stuff = data[i].split(',')
    print stuff[1], stuff[2]
    lat = float(stuff[1])
    lon = float(stuff[2])
    x = webMercX(lon, zoom) - cx
    y = webMercY(lat, zoom) - cy
    i += 1
```

The other functions of above script are unnecessary but when I run it, I get the following error.

```
while i < len(data):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Because `print` doesn't returns anything :), You are not returning anything from `csv_to_array `

Comment: Wow, that was a stupid mistake (which I fixed just now), but now I get the following error:

    my_file = open(b, "rb")
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Response found

It's not recognizing the URL as a string

Comment: Now you're just returning the *first line* of the file. The function immediately ends on the first `return`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most suggestions are comments in the code, but a few general ones:

1. Use better names
2. Return immediately quits out of the function, if you use `yield` you can generate line after line

New code with learning experiences:

```
def csv_to_array(url): # use descriptive variable names
    response = requests.get(url)
    lines = response.text.splitlines() # you don't need an open...the data is already loaded
    for line in lines[1:]: # skip first line (has headers)
        el = [i.strip() for i in line.split(',')]
        yield el # don't return, that immediately ends the function

data = csv_to_array("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.csv")

for row in data: # don't use indexes, just iterate over the data
    # you already split on commas.
    print(row[1], row[2]) # again, better names
    lat = float(row[1])
    lon = float(row[2])
#     x = webMercX(lon, zoom) - cx
#     y = webMercY(lat, zoom) - cy
```

Code for the lazy:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.csv')
```

[image]

Comment: For plotting on google map, I'd take a look at gmplot.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your first function with generator that iterates over a response data and yields arrays for each line of the file

```
def csv_to_array(a):
    response = requests.get(a) 
    # you can access response's body via text attribute
    for line in response.text.split('\n'):
        yield [i.strip() for i in line.split(',')]


list(csv_to_array(some_url))
```